# question about circular law

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

Hi,

I have a question about the circular law.
Consider $A_n=[x_{ij}]$ a sequence of random matrices where $x_{ij}$ are iid with mean $0$ and variance $1$. Consider $\lambda_{n,1},\dots,\lambda_{n,n}$ the eigenvalues of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} A_n$ and 
$\mu_n$ the random measure $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \delta_{\lambda_{n,k}}$ on $\mathbb{C}$.
The circular law (see the paper of Tao-Vu-Krishnapur, 2010, annals of proba) states that 
for each test function $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \\mathbb{C}$ one has almost surely 
$$ \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty} \int_{\mathbb{C}} f(z) d\mu_n = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{p^2+q^2\leq 1} f(p+iq) dpdq        $$

By test function, we mean continuous and compactly supported. Is the same conclusion also true if $f$ is the caracteristic function of a closed subset of $\mathbb{C}$ ?
Here is a simple example, consider a closed subset $F\subset \mathbb{C}$
with zero Lebesgue measure, is it true that 
$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty} \mathbb{P}( \forall k \in [1,n], \lambda_{n,k}\in F    ) =0         $$

Thanks,

Comment: By Urysohn's lemma, you can approximate $1_F$ from above in $L^1$ by a sequence of continuous compactly supported functions, $(f_n)$, and below by 0. Applying the result of the TVK paper to the $f_n$'s, you get a slightly weaker conclusion than you're asking for.

Comment: Which $L^1$ space are you thinking about ?
with the Lebesgue measure or $\mu_n$ measures ?

So you say that the answer of my question would be affirmative ?

Comment: The (non-random) $L^1$ space with Lebesgue measure. This will mean the right side of the TVK equality (which is an upper bound) converges to 0. *But* this only gives that $\mathbb E\mu_{n}(F)\to 0$, which is a weaker conclusion than you asked for.